# Why is mongodump not working on my Windows machine?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a backup of my mongodb from Atlas, using the Atlas-provided string:

`mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@MYCLUSTER.c7uv8.mongodb.net`

I'm running the code on Windows in the system command line. I know that the string "c:/golang" is created by set_goenv.sh from mongotools (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/master/set_goenv.sh), but the rest is a mystery. Any help would be appreciated!

````
PC=0x2360000
signal arrived during external code execution

syscall.loadsystemlibrary(0xc000018be0, 0xc00001c740, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:137 +0x11d
syscall.LoadDLL(0xbcbd8f, 0xa, 0xc000004180, 0x469231, 0xc000116e18)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:80 +0x168
syscall.(*LazyDLL).Load(0xc000004180, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:236 +0xa9
syscall.(*LazyProc).Find(0xc000057710, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:291 +0xa4
syscall.(*LazyProc).mustFind(0xc000057710)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:309 +0x32
syscall.(*LazyProc).Addr(0xc000057710, 0x2b)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:318 +0x32
syscall._DnsQuery(0xc000054240, 0x21, 0x0, 0xc000117020, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go:1699 +0x3b
syscall.DnsQuery(0xc00001a570, 0x2b, 0x21, 0x0, 0xc000117020, 0x0, 0x8, 0x30000)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go:1695 +0xb5
net.(*Resolver).lookupSRV(0x12d8800, 0xe821e0, 0xc00001e2a8, 0xbca98c, 0x7, 0xbc9af6, 0x3, 0xc000022117, 0x1d, 0x0, ...)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/net/lookup_windows.go:229 +0x10c
net.LookupSRV(0xbca98c, 0x7, 0xbc9af6, 0x3, 0xc000022117, 0x1d, 0xe76820, 0xc000005c20, 0x12d9e60, 0x2190008, ...)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/net/lookup.go:396 +0xad
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/dns.(*Resolver).fetchSeedlistFromSRV(0xa8bfa0, 0xc000022117, 0x1d, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0001e6650, 0x1, 0x1)
        C:/data/mci/809418cde33d2ca64c5cf3e779268efd/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/dns/dns.go:78 +0xb6
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/dns.(*Resolver).ParseHosts(0xa8bfa0, 0xc000022117, 0x1d, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0001e6640, 0x1, 0x1)
        C:/data/mci/809418cde33d2ca64c5cf3e779268efd/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/dns/dns.go:34 +0x157
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/connstring.(*parser).parse(0xc0000d8840, 0xc0000220f0, 0x44, 0x203000000000000, 0x21effff)
        C:/data/mci/809418cde33d2ca64c5cf3e779268efd/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/connstring/connstring.go:257 +0xdb0
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/connstring.Parse(0xc0000220f0, 0x44, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        C:/data/mci/809418cde33d2ca64c5cf3e779268efd/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/connstring/connstring.go:44 +0xbe
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/options.(*ToolOptions).NormalizeOptionsAndURI(0xc00019f970, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/data/mci/809418cde33d2ca64c5cf3e779268efd/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/options/options.go:504 +0x125
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/options.(*ToolOptions).ParseArgs(0xc00019f970, 0xc000005bc0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xe7fca0, 0x28, 0xbf0cb7, 0x145, 0x101010101)
        C:/data/mci/809418cde33d2ca64c5cf3e779268efd/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/options/options.go:447 +0x14f
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump.ParseOptions(0xc000026150, 0x2, 0x3, 0xe66cc8, 0x7, 0xe7fca0, 0x28, 0x40d2e3, 0xc000051ab0, 0x10, ...)
        C:/data/mci/809418cde33d2ca64c5cf3e779268efd/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump/options.go:88 +0x14e
main.main()
        C:/data/mci/809418cde33d2ca64c5cf3e779268efd/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump/main/mongodump.go:33 +0xb2

goroutine 6 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:139 +0xa3
os/signal.loop()
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:23 +0x29
created by os/signal.init.0
        c:/golang/go1.12/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:29 +0x48
rax     0x7ffb1d3f4c42
rbx     0x7ffb1d3f4c40
rcx     0x5f
rdi     0xffffffffffbadd11
rsi     0x0
rbp     0x2235e90
rsp     0x218f3b0
r8      0x0
r9      0x0
r10     0x0
r11     0x94b
r12     0x7ffb20f40000
r13     0x0
r14     0x7ffb1d3f4c42
r15     0xc000007a
rip     0x2360000
rflags  0x10206
cs      0x33
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so problem solved...by waiting 30 minutes and running the same command with -v enabled.

Now I can run the above command without an error, with or without -v. I literally just went to go get coffee and now it works.